# Logical entailments of the verb frighten

Tags: grammaticality

Are the following entailments (examples 1-2) and sentences (examples 3-4) possible and well-formed?

1. Tom frightened Mary and he still frightens her.
2. Tom frightened Mary and he didn't stop frightening her.
3. Tom frightened Mary for a while.
4. Tom frightened Mary in 10 hours.

Without the provision of any context, does the sentence Tom frightened Mary entail that she was frightened by Tom once in the past and she stopped being frightened by him?

Comment: It is unclear what you perceive as the difference between the first two and the second two cases; all four of them are sentences. If you are asking different questions about 1-2 and about 3-4, you should separate them more clearly. Also an entailment must be an entailment **of** something: is your question whether 1 and 2 are entailed by 'Tom frightened Mary'? And how is the last sentence of the question related to 1-4?

Comment: If the 'frightening' was continuing rather than a single experience, it would be more natural to say 'Mary was frightened/afraid of Tom'.

Comment: What is 4 supposed to mean? Was she frightened a period of 10 hours, or at a time 10 hours from now, or it took him 10 hours to make her afraid, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

> Without the provision of any context,

Without the provision of any context, English become incomprehensible. It is **impossible** to over-emphasise the importance of context in a synthetic language.

If I say to you "It is big" without any context, how big is it? Is it really big?

As general guidance, which may or may not fit your imagined context, the simple form of the verb indicates one instance **as a whole - from start to finish** (and may include preparations).

The simple form may indicate a series of completed actions and thus indicate repeated/ habitual/ frequent/ regular instances of the action.

Tom frightened Mary [each time he appeared] and he still frightens her [each time he appears].

Tom frightened Mary [on one occasion] and he didn't stop frightening her [the continuous form has other guidance - it indicates an action that has started but, **at the time referred to**, has not stopped].

Tom frightened Mary [on one/several occasion/s] for a while.

Tom frightened Mary in 10 hours. -> It took Tom 10 hours to frighten Mary.

> and she stopped being frightened by him?

It says **nothing** about the after-effects.

Answer (score 0):

*Frighten,* devoid of context, is an ambiguous verb. It's an old causative, like *lengthen* and *whiten*, and thus means *cause fright*. But *fright* is an animal reaction and requires causes and experiencers. These can show up in different places. It can have an active sense, as in

- *The fireworks last night frightened all of us, not just the dogs.*

which refers to past events and their temporary emotional results. Note that the cause of the emotions is the subject, and the experiencers of the emotion are the objects.

But *frighten* also has another use (especially in the predicate adjective *frightened* formed from its past participle). It can refer to permanent or recurrent emotional attitudes, as in

- *Mary/Skiing/Math/That frightens me.*
- *I'm frightened of Mary/skiing/math/that.*

Note that with this stative emotional verb, the causer can also be subject, but the passive construction is normally indistinguishable from the predicate adjective, and it's grown to be just another emotional word:

- *He's just frightened/scared/confused/yellow/a coward.*

without requiring any cause.

So, as to the original question, devoid of context, one can't tell what happened in the past, nor whether that's stopped in the present or not. All one can tell is the description of the emotion (*fear*) and maybe who is experiencing it. None of the entailments go through.